# evaluate XPath expression in indesign

Tags: xpath, applescript, adobe-indesign

I tried this code:

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
   set ParaIdOrSecId to "ti0005"
   set xpa to "//*[@*='" & ParaIdOrSecId & "']" as string
   tell active document
      tell XML element 1    
         set Requriedxpa to evaluate XPath expression using xpa 
      end tell
   end tell
end tell
```

After executing, InDesign Shows a dialog box:

> Content contains characters which cannot be encoded.

Why am I not able to execute it, even though its a valid xpath?

Comment: InDesign speaks about the _content_. Have you looked at it? Can you provide minimal example content to reproduce the issue (read about [building an sscce](http://www.sscce.org))?

Comment: hi jens erat Indesign Content contains Indent to her tab thats y it shows "Content contains characters which cannot be encoded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not limited to XPath, I know it from other XML features such as export. One typical character to cause the dialog is the right aligned tab (entered as shift-tab). With export it helps to just disable the dialog, because the dialog is wired straight into internal XML streaming and does not produce an error / exception:

```
set user interaction level of script preferences to never interact
```

Comment: thanks Dirk,it works,Indesign Contents contains Indent to her tab thats y i can't execute this code